# Error al refrescar proyecto con gradle

Tags: android-studio

He descargado un open source de una app de hoteles, la app la puedo exportar sin ningun problema al android studio y poder visualizarla en el emulador, pero a la hora de verla en el activity_main.xml la seccion de DESING no puedo y me aparece esto
[image: Primera captura]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Instale la version 25.0 Pero sigo sin conseguir visualizar

Comment: has probado a cambiar el API a la hora de intentar visualizarlo? Yo utilizo android studio y a veces hay que hacerlo. Donde está el muñequito de android que pone null (en la zona superior) pulsa y ves probando APIs a ver si en algún punto se te ve, yo por ejemplo la visualizo con la api 19, con la 25 me da errores

Comment: Si lo he probado, pero aun no me visualiza el design.

Comment: Ya has presionado el mensaje de error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema surge cuando **gradle** no puede descargar unos archivos importantes para la compilación del proyecto o cuando estos archivos están corruptos. Estos archivos se pueden dañar durante la descarga, ya sea por un fallo en la conexión a Internet o alguna otra razón.

### Solucion:

Si ha tratado de solucionar el problema presionando sobre los **links** que presenta el mensaje de error, se dará cuenta de que no pasa nada y de que no da solución al problema.

Para solucionar el problema, primero es necesario borrar los archivos corruptos y después volverlos a descargar. Para saber cuales son los archivos corruptos, abra el archivo **gradle-wrapper.properties** y al final de la ultima linea de este archivo, encontrara el nombre del archivo corrupto.

[image: archivo gradle-wrapper.properties]

La ubicación de estos archivos por lo general es la ruta: **C:\Users\USER\.gradle\wrapper\dists**

En la carpeta **dists** debe busca y eliminar la carpeta que posee el mismo nombre que el archivo corrupto. En este caso es la carpeta **gradle-2.10-all**. Esta carpeta es la que contiene los archivos corruptos.

[image: carpeta dists]

Con la carpeta que contiene los archivos corruptos borrada, vuelva a descargar los archivos presionando el enlace que se muestra en el mensaje de error. Al presionar el enlace se volverán a descargar los archivos y se solucionara el problema. Cuando presione el enlace, se le mostrara un **progress bar** como el siguiente:

[image: Refrescando proyecto]

Solo resta esperar que el proyecto termine de refrescarse y listo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, solucionado!

Comment: Muchas gracias, @DavidMInaya, tu respuesta solucionó el problema sólo que luego me dió el siguiente error: > Failed to execute aapt. Entonces me informé de que ese error se soluciona añadiendo en gradle.properties esta línea: android.enableAapt2=false. Resulta que no tenía archivo gradle.properties, lo creé y añadí la instrucción, y funcionó. Intenté votarte, pero al tener menos de 15 puntos de reputación mi voto no se muestra.