# Error al importar proyecto a Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Necesito importar un proyecto de Android Studio ya creado a Android Studio, pero tengo el problema que me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En "Event log" me sale el siguiente error:

> Gradle sync failed: Cause: failed to find target android-23 : C:\Users\theda\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>               Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1s 338ms)

La cosa está en que le doy a "Install..." y parece que se instala lo que pide, pero una vez hecho sigue aparecido el mismo error.

Entiendo que es algo normal al importar un proyecto existente así que tiene que haber una solución fácil.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: dale en Show Log, para ver que te muestra

Comment: @MarcusF Usas Android Studio 3.0 y estas tratando de importar un proyecto con una versión de Android Studio anterior?

Comment: @Jorgesys efectivamente es 3.0, pero ni idea de la versión del proyecto a importar. ¿Se puede saber de alguna forma? En algún archivo del proyecto,...

Comment: @diegoveloper no encuentro la opción que comentas.

Comment: es irrelevante, solo asegura dar click y al terminar la instalación invalida el caché.

Comment: @MarcusF para ver el Log, ve al menú y entra a Help > Show  Log in Explorer.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error al refrescar proyecto con gradle](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119607/error-al-refrescar-proyecto-con-gradle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da click en el texto azul, eso provocara la instalación de la API faltante que en este caso es la 23:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es común que en ocasiones no detecte la instalación, por lo tanto tienes que realizar la eliminación del caché mediante:

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es lo que finalmente me ha funcionado. Aún así después me ha salido un error distinto (
Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix()) pero una vez resuelto todo va perfectamente. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta desactivando el Instan Run en Android, Presiona Ctrl + Alt + S

Luego en la ventana dirigete aqui : Build,Execution, Deployment 
[image: Settings]

Otra opcion si el proyecto que tienes esta utilizando otra SDK mira el gradle
y en el mindSDK reemplazalo por el 19, a mi me funciono asi al subir un proyecto antiguo...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]