# Problemas luego de actualizar Android Studio a la versión 3.1

Tags: android, gradle, build

Luego de actualizar a la versión 3.1 he querido ejecutar el proyecto (que funcionaba perfectamente) en el emulador y aparecieron varios errores.

```
C:\Users\david\AndroidStudioProjects\SistemaCtrlProdRealTime\app\src\main\java\com\example\david\sistemactrlprodrealtime\AppDatabase.java:15: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
```

Ese es el primero..... luego :

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
```

:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED

Y por último :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:

Seguido de una larga lista de archivos .jar (que son los ficheros a los que quiere "mergear").

Cualquier sugerencia será bienvenida.

Comment: Hola, invalidaste cache y reiniciaste? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/120938/error-al-importar-proyecto-a-android-studio/120942#120942

Answer (score 1):

Es común que en ocasiones no detecte la instalación, por lo tanto tienes que realizar la eliminación del caché mediante:

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar la alerta

> Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so
>   we cannot export the schema. You can either provide
>   `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set
>   exportSchema to false.

En el archivo `app.gradle` añadir en defaultconfig

```
defaultConfig {
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
        }
    }
}
```

o en **Kotlin**

```
kapt {
    arguments {
        arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }
}
```