# error gradle sync

Tags: android-studio, gradle, groovy, build

desde que actualicé a  `android studio 3.0.1` no puedo continuar con mi aplicación. Gradle arroja el siguiente error: Gradle Sync Issues

> **Error:Unable to load class 'groovy.lang.GroovyObject'**. Possible causes
>   for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache
>     may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection
>     timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync
>     project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build
>     process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve
>     this problem. Stop Gradle build processes
>     (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party
>     plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project
>     or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the
>   case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and
>   then killing all Java processes.

Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119607/error-al-refrescar-proyecto-con-gradle/119626#119626) que le di a otro usuario te puede ser de utilidad.

Comment: Actualizaste desde una versión anterior a 3.0 ?

Comment: sí, actualicé desde una versión anterior a 3.0

Comment: @DavidMinaya me fue útil tu respuesta, sólo que luego me dió el siguiente error: > Failed to execute aapt. Entonces me informé de que ese error se soluciona añadiendo en gradle.properties esta línea: android.enableAapt2=false.  Resulta que no tenía archivo gradle.properties, lo creé y añadí la instrucción, y funcionó.

Comment: Pues eso esta bien, añade un comentario a mi respuesta explicando esa solución y también recuerda dar las gracias de manera constructiva (como dando un voto a favor) tal como explican en el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio.